# dotnet core : Can not find assembly file Microsoft.CSharp.dll

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a project that i have not run for some while, build with dotnet core 1.1.2 dependencies.

in the meanwhile I have updated visual studio, possible installed some dotnet core stuff for 2.0 and my application do not run anymore.

```
InvalidOperationException: Can not find assembly file Microsoft.CSharp.dll at 'C:\dev\EarthML\EarthML.Mapify\src\EarthML.Mapify.Portal\bin\Debug\net462\win10-x64\refs,C:\dev\EarthML\EarthML.Mapify\src\EarthML.Mapify.Portal\bin\Debug\net462\win10-x64\'
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.Resolution.AppBaseCompilationAssemblyResolver.TryResolveAssemblyPaths(CompilationLibrary library, List<string> assemblies)
```

What would I do to start figuring out why it dont work?

Comment: According to your exception, it's noting `net462\win10-x64`. I would highly suspect your `.csproj` file needs to be reviewed. If you wouldn't mind sharing that?

Comment: I upgraded the application to dotnet core 2.0 and razor pages and got around the issue.

Comment: It looks like your assembly path is missing the GAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded the application to dotnet core 2.0 and razor pages and got around the issue.

Comment: i upgraded to 2.0 and the issue still exists. :( Anything else u changed?

Answer (score 13):

This seems to be a bug with the current version of Visual Studio (15.3). The underlying problem is when the Views are trying to build, they are not referencing the GAC, and thus, have none of their dependencies.

While only a work-around, your best bet when encountering this problem is to copy over the missing DLLs. I set them up as components in my project with a copy action. Once it gets fixed (currently Triaged: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96927/runtime-error-after-upgrading-to-vs-153-invalidope.html), then it's a matter of deleting them.

EDIT

Alternately, according to https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1488, adding this as a reference to the project should work instead of adding all the dependencies:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="2.0.0" />
```

Comment: This fix didn't work for me- were you already on .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: No. But moving to 2.0 will fix your problems.

Comment: Sorry, do you know what about the upgrade actually fixes this?

Comment: No. Sorry. The issue is currently "Under Investigation" according to the developercommunity link in the answer.

Comment: The package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` reference? Expand your project, right click on `References`, click `Add Reference`, search `Microsoft.CSharp`, check the box, click `OK`.

[image: Select Microsoft.CSharp]

Comment: Yes, and also added the nuget Microsoft.CSharp 4.3.0

Comment: but its not in the output bin folder

Answer (score 1):

I had `<DependsOnNETStandard>true</DependsOnNETStandard>` and I had to change it to `<DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard1.6</DependsOnNETStandard>`

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <IsServiceFabricServiceProject>True</IsServiceFabricServiceProject>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject</AssemblyName>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard1.6</DependsOnNETStandard>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Source: From neman on [GitHub Isue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1488#issuecomment-323350555)

Answer (score 0):

In my C# project, a few .NET Standard classlib's support a Core console application and a Winforms .net 4.7 program. Yesterday I opened my project, one of the .NET standard dll's gave above error, leaving references with an exclamation mark, same for  all libs that depend on it in the solution ! It looked very alarming.

I kept working on my solution, though.. I use Visual Studio 15.8.1 here, the issue seems to be a spook. A fake warning. The exclamation marks remain while working on the project, but nothing happens, it does not disturb anything or interrupt rebuilds. The assembly runs as expected.

Few minutes ago I solved it, by *removing* the Microsoft.CSharp reference, then rebuild all. It was in only one library, so the rebuild solved all exclamation marks in the solution. The reference has gone away, clear sky.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where in a .net standard was using "dynamic" type which is there in "Microsoft.CSharp". The project was building from Visual studio but was failing from azure devops release pipeline. adding reference from nuget solved the problem.

Install via  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CSharp/
Reference (Credits): https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/net-core-standard-missing-compiler-required-member

Answer (score -9):

clean the solution and rebuild it .
if not worked create new project then copy dll and paste .
good luck .