# Refs folder not created during dotnet build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a ASP.NET app with a number of references (e.g. Microsoft.CSharp, System, System.ComponentModel, etc...).  When I run `dotnet publish`, everything works fine.  In particular, a `refs` folder is created in the published directory with the referenced DLLs.

However, upon running `dotnet build` and `dotnet run`, this `refs` folder is not created, and consequently, I receive an error upon compiling the MVC views:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find reference assembly
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.dll' file for package microsoft.csharp

If I *manually* copy the `refs` directory created during publish into the same directory that my `.exe` lives in after running `dotnet build`, then this error goes away.  My question is, why isn't the `refs` folder being created?

I have tried everything except upgrading to .NET Core 2.0 in this answer ([dotnet core : Can not find assembly file Microsoft.CSharp.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380712/dotnet-core-can-not-find-assembly-file-microsoft-csharp-dll)), and tried included the line `<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>` in my `.csproj` file.  I've also tried most of everything from this GitHub thread (https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4177).

Comment: is it solved???

Comment: Like @anatol I'm also wondering if this has been solved.