# There was a conflict between "System.Net.Http"

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, nuget

When I try to build my Asp .Net Core (1.1.2) App, I'm receiving the following warning:

> Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that could not be resolved. These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

This then turns into a runtime error so I'm trying to fix this warning...

I turned on detailed logging in Visual Studio and I see this in the build output window:

```
There was a conflict between "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Users\mdepouw\.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.1\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll].
        C:\Users\mdepouw\.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.1\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\mdepouw\.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.1\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll".
            System.Net.Http
    References which depend on "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Users\mdepouw\Source\Repos\MyProject\MyProject.Services.Common\bin\x64\Debug\System.Net.Http.dll].
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.applicationinsights.aspnetcore\2.1.1\lib\net451\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.applicationinsights.aspnetcore\2.1.1\lib\net451\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll".
            C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.applicationinsights.aspnetcore\2.1.1\lib\net451\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll
        C:\Users\mdepouw\Source\Repos\MyProject\MyProject.Services.Common\bin\x64\Debug\MyProject.Services.Common.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\mdepouw\Source\Repos\MyProject\MyProject.Services.Common\bin\x64\Debug\MyProject.Services.Common.dll".
            C:\Users\mdepouw\Source\Repos\MyProject\MyProject.Services.Common\bin\x64\Debug\MyProject.Services.Common.dll
        C:\Users\mdepouw\Source\Repos\MyProject\MyProject.Services.Common\bin\x64\Debug\MyProject.Persistence.MarkLogic.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\mdepouw\Source\Repos\MyProject\MyProject.Services.Common\bin\x64\Debug\MyProject.Persistence.MarkLogic.dll".
            C:\Users\mdepouw\Source\Repos\MyProject\MyProject.Services.Common\bin\x64\Debug\MyProject.Services.Common.dll

          ... more dlls that reference 4.1.1.2
```

---

**Dependencies**

[image: nuget references screenshot]

[image: assembly references screenshot]

---

I don't understand the part that tells me which "References" depend upon `System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0`.  I'm reading it as it depends upon itself.  What am I misunderstanding?

I'm not referencing `System.Net.Http` directly either via Assembly references nor as a Nuget reference.

Also, the file in "C:\Users\mdepouw.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.1\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll" is version `4.1.1.0`.

Comment: It means two different packages (or other projects in the solution which you link) you use reference different versions of the `System.Net.Http` assembly. Have a look Dependencies > `NETStandard 2.0` or `.NET Core 2.0` (or just "Dependencies when you only have a single target) and list the dependencies. Easier if you use "Search Solution Explorer" field and type "System.Net.Http" in it and see which libraries have a dependency on it

Comment: This often happens when you mix stuff, like some old beta or rc with a release or ASP.NET Core 1.x with 2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: The original fix worked for my WebApi but didn't work for Viewing MVC Pages.  I started to receive another runtime exception: [Can not find assembly file Microsoft.CSharp.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45380712/185123).

I changed `<DependsOnNETStandard>true</DependsOnNETStandard>` to `<DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard1.6</DependsOnNETStandard>` and that resolved the issue.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <IsServiceFabricServiceProject>True</IsServiceFabricServiceProject>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject</AssemblyName>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard1.6</DependsOnNETStandard>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

---

**Original Answer**:

I added `<DependsOnNETStandard>true</DependsOnNETStandard>` per [this GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/730#issuecomment-313152425) Issue and my build warning went away and so did my runtime error.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <IsServiceFabricServiceProject>True</IsServiceFabricServiceProject>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject</AssemblyName>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <DependsOnNETStandard>true</DependsOnNETStandard>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

Comment: Good point.  I wanted to wait a little while in case it truly work or somebody had a better idea!

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand the part that tells me which "References" depend upon System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0. I'm reading it as it depends upon itself. What am I misunderstanding?

That because one of dependencies for `Microsoft.AspNetCore` drags in `NETStandard.Library 1.6` which adds tons of System.* dependencies:

[image]

> There was a conflict between “System.Net.Http”

This is a known issue about .NET core:

[System.Net.Http package 4.3.2 - redirect to 4.2.0.0, assembly loading failure](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22781#issuecomment-322694600)

This issue will be fixed in the next version 2.1.0.

The current workaround provided by Tornhoof:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.2" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>      
</assemblyBinding>
```

It uses the dll from the build extensions directory and not the one from Nuget.

Comment: Thanks for the response Leo.  My app is an ASP.Net Core 1.1.2 app though; not 2.0.  I've updated my question w/ my dependencies.